# Significato di "perder la pancia" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> – Ma non sai tutto. Dal giorno che Ginotta m’è andata via, io vi ho addosso tutt’e quattro voi uomini. E ti dico che mi fate **perder la pancia**, e chissà se la duro.
>           – Cosa vi sentite? 
>           – Soltanto stanchità per adesso, ma una gran stanchità.

La mia domanda è sul senso dell'espressione "perder la pancia" che appare in questo passaggio.
Significa semplicemente perdere peso? O ha invece qualche significato figurato? Ho cercato alla voce "pancia" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato questa espressione.

Comment: Ha un senso sicuramente figurato, significa che il peso/responsabilità dei quattro uomini è talmente faticoso da non lasciare il tempo di riposare (e quindi  metter su pancia). È come dire _mi prosciugate le energie_ oppure _mi fate perdere la salute_.

Comment: È possibile che faccia riferimento a dei problemi finanziari? Del tipo "ora che Ginotta non abita più qui, con un solo stipendio faccio fatica a mandare avanti la casa e mi tocca tirare la cinghia"

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quella che pronuncia queste parole è la padrona della casa dove lavora come contadino Agostino, l'io narrante e l'interlocutore di questo dialogo. Ginotta è sua figlia che è andata via perché si è sposata. Più che dei problemi finanziari, penso che si tratti del fatto che questa donna non abbia più nessuno che gli dia una mano con le faccende domestiche. Né Ginotta né sua madre lavorano fuori di casa, ma questa donna fa un lavoro molto duro come contadina.